# How do I prove a SEQUENCE of functions $f_n(x)$ is continuous? (I only have been taught the regular definition.)

Tags: real-analysis

I know from the definition of continuity (General Metric Form) that if a function $f(x)$ is continuous at point $a$, then we have the following:

Let $(M_1,d_1)$ and $(M_2,d_2)$ be metric spaces and let $a \in M_1$ and $f$ be a function from $M_1 \to M_2$. $f$ is continuous at $a$ if for every $\epsilon >0$, there exists a $\delta >0$ such that if $d_1(x,a)<\delta$, then $d_2(f(x),f(a))<\epsilon$.

Similarly, $f$ is continuous on $M_1$ if $f$ is continuous at every point of $M_1$.

However, when we are talking about sequences of functions, say $f_n(x)$, I am completely thrown off. I am not sure how to show it with the $n$ involved in the function. Does anyone know how I can prove it?

For example, I am trying to show that $f_n(x) = (1-x)^n$ is continuous on the interval $[0,1]$ but am having a lot of trouble because the $n$ term keeps appearing in the above definition. Thanks!

Comment: *Sequences* aren't continuous, individual functions are. The fact that a function $f_n$ is a term in a sequence is irrelevant. Each $f_n$ is a polynomial, so $f_n$ is continuous.

Answer (score 0):

It just means you need to show that for all $n$, $f_n$ is continuous.

One thing worth keeping in mind is the following.  We can take your definition for continuity and write it in the language of predicate logic:

$$(\forall a \in M_1)(\forall \epsilon > 0)(\exists \delta > 0)(\forall x \in M_1)\left[(d_1(x,a) < \delta) \Longrightarrow (d_2(f(x), f(a)) < \epsilon)\right]$$

Since the $\exists \delta$ comes after the $\forall \epsilon$, you're allowed to choose your $\delta$ in terms of $\epsilon$.  For example, for $f(x) = x$, you'd typically choose $\delta = \epsilon$.

Now you're just being asked to show that a whole family of functions is each continuous.  That's expressed as:

$$(\forall n \in \mathbb{N})(\forall a \in [0,1])(\forall \epsilon > 0)(\exists \delta > 0)(\forall x \in M_1)\left[(d_1(x,a) < \delta) \Longrightarrow (d_2(f_n(x), f_n(a)) < \epsilon)\right]$$

Because the $\exists \delta$ comes after *both* the $\forall n$ and $\forall \epsilon$, your choice for $\delta$ can (and in this case, must) depend on both $n$ and $\epsilon$.

So for $n=1$, given some $\epsilon$, you'd choose $\delta = \epsilon$ to prove continuity for $f_n$.  But for $n=2$, given some $\epsilon$, you wouldn't choose $\delta = \epsilon$, that wouldn't work.  But you don't have to, you're free to have $\delta$ differently because you're proving it for a different $n$.

Obviously, you can't manually write out a proof for each individual $n$, so you'll have to solve the problem in general for all $n$.  It'll amount to coming up with some general expression for $\delta$ written in terms of $\epsilon$ and $n$, e.g. $\epsilon \cdot n$.

Hint, $\epsilon \cdot n$ is not the right choice. :)